# What's missing in this Angular service Jasmine test?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jasmine2.0

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/9IBj4944IXxXm6O5CjmP?p=preview) I have an Angular service that is tested by a Jasmine test. The test apparently cannot find the service, I get

> Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/unpr?p0=UtilsProvider%20%3C-%20Utils

and also

> Error: Declaration Location

What's the problem here?

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("app", [])

app.service('Utils', function(){

    this.sum = function(a, b) {
          return a + b;
    };

});


describe("Testing Service Utils", function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        angular.module("app");
    });

    it('should sum',
        inject(function(Utils) {
            expect(Utils.sum(1,2)).to.equal(3);
    }));

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems...

1. In order to register module configurations for testing, you need to use [`angular.mock.module`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module)

   ```
   beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'))
   // or simply beforeEach(module('app'))
   ```
2. The equality assertion is `toEqual`, not `to.equal`

   ```
   expect(Utils.sum(1,2)).toEqual(3)
   ```

http://plnkr.co/edit/UZfKILseNklw2MgO2l8c?p=preview